Does an isomorphism of maps on etale covers descend to an isomorphism?
Suppose $X$ is a scheme and $Y$ is an algebraic space and let $f_1, f_2$ be two morphisms from $X$ to $Y.$ Let $\alpha \colon U \to X$ and $\beta \colon V \to Y$ be etale surjective maps. Suppose there exist $g_i \colon U \to V$ such that $\beta g_i = f_i\alpha$ for $i = 1,2.$ In other words, we have the following commutative diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
U @>{g_i}>> V;\\
@V \alpha VV @VV \beta V \\
X @>{f_i}>> Y
\end{CD}$$
Suppose $g_1$ and $g_2$ are isomorphic. Does this imply that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are isomorphic? It seems like this should be related to descent, but I am not quite sure how the descent data and cocycle conditions come into play here.
Edit: Perhaps for some context, I am interested in the case when $Y$ is some coarse moduli space, and I want to prove the uniqueness part of the valuative criterion. If we can show that the two maps are isomorphic on etale covers, does that allow us to conclude that the original maps in $Y(X)$ were isomorphic?

What if $X=U=V$?

What is the point of considering two morphisms? Could you not just look at one of them at a time for this question?

@AlexYoucis Then perhaps we could take $\alpha$ to be the identity, and $g_i$ would be automorphisms of $X.$ So $f_i = \beta g_i$ would be isomorphic?

@Daniel I added some context for clarification!
